# PDO bindValue isn't allowing a specific parameter to pass through (PHP)

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using PHP with PDO for PostgreSQL. I am getting weird behavior when I try to bind a specific value into my query. What I have is the following:

```
$value[0][$i] = "'%{$filtervalue}%'";
$values[] = & $value[0][$i];
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(':condition', $values[0]);
$result->bindValue(':starts', $start);
$result->bindValue(':pagesize', $pagesize);
```

Now the `$query` parameter returns back

```
SELECT orderDate, shippeddate, shipName, 
shipaddress, shipcity, shipcountry 
FROM orders  WHERE ( shipcity LIKE :condition ) 
LIMIT :pagesize OFFSET :starts
```

which is exactly what I want. However the issue is with the `$vales[0]` parameter because `$pagesize` and `$start` work fine.

When I execute with the `$vales[0]` parameter the results returns back nothing.

However, when I change

```
$result->bindValue(':condition', $values[0]);
```

To

```
$result->bindValue(':condition', '%Bern%');
```

it works for that particular condition and the results are shown.

I doubled checked to make sure `$values[0]` returns back `'%Bern%'` and it does.

I even checked to see the type is string and it is.

I even added `PDO::PARAM_STR` and still nothing.

I ran out of ideas on why it isn't working.

Comment: `$value[0][$i] = "'%{$filtervalue}%'";$values[] = & $value[0][$i];` needs to be `$value[0][$i] = "%{$filtervalue}%";$values[] = $value[0][$i];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 changes needed:

`$value[0][$i] = "'%{$filtervalue}%'";` needs to be `$value[0][$i] = "%{$filtervalue}%";`

And

`$values[] = & $value[0][$i];` needs to be `$values[] = $value[0][$i];`

***Note:-*** You can directly use `$value[0][$i]`, no need to create an extra variable, do like this:

```
$value[0][$i] = "%{$filtervalue}%";
$result = $pdo->prepare($query);
$result->bindValue(':condition', $value[0][$i]);
$result->bindValue(':starts', $start);
$result->bindValue(':pagesize', $pagesize);
```